# Split Text in Powerapps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I have a `TextInput1` on my Powerapps, I want to split the text in that textbox and save each individual value as a variable in memory

I used following code in the items property of comboBox, The following code return the split text as a table datatype so, it works on combobox but I couldn't figure out how to save the values individually in memory like var1, var2 and so on.

Split(
TextInput1.Text,
"   "
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know exactly how many parts the string would have you can use the Index function to take the items that were returned, something like this:

```
With(
    { parts: Split(TextInput1.Text, " ") },
    UpdateContext( {
        var1: Index(parts, 1).Value,
        var2: Index(parts, 2).Value,
        var3: Index(parts, 3).Value
    } ))
```

If you don't know, you can store the result in a collection - and this collection can be used in controls such as a gallery or combo boxes, for example:

```
ClearCollect( parts, Split( TextInput1.Text, " " ) )
```

Or

```
Set( parts, Split( TextInput1.Text, " " ) )
```